# Using ScalaCheck to generate database data

Tags: database, scala, testing, scalacheck

Is there a way to generate faked database data using ScalaCheck? For example, if I pump in my database schema definitions to ScalaCheck is there a way it can generate what I need to test each model I have? Is there a way for it to maintain referential integrity?

Comment: AFAIK you have to create the generators yourself. Probably you can create a generic function using reflection/macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually create generators for the models. You can create an arbitrary instance for any object and class from a generator. For instance:

`case class Hoge(a: String, b: Int)` can be easily generated:

```
val hogeGen: Generator[Hoge] = for {
  aGen <- arbitrary[String]
  bGen <- arbitrary[Int]
} yield Hoge(aGen, bGen)
```

In order to use this automatically in your property test, you will need an implicit arbitrary instance of the generator. I suggest including the type when writing these to avoid issues.

```
implicit val arbHoge: Arbitrary[Hoge] = Arbitrary(hogeGen)
```

You could also skip the generator step and just write `implicit val arbHoge: Arbitrary[Hoge] = Arbitrary(for { ... } yield Hoge(...))`

But if you're dealing with some realtional database, its likely that you'll have nested structures.

```
case class Fuga(h: Hoge, i: Int)
```

Since you have already defined the generator for `Hoge`, we can write a generator for `Fuga` the same way.

```
val fugaGen: Generator[Fuga] = for {
  hGen <- hogeGen
  iGen <- arbitrary[Int]
} yield Fuga(hGen, iGen)
```

You could also use the arbitrary instance of Hoge the same way we used the standard arbitrary integer available in scalacheck with `arbitrary[Hoge]`

And one last note, if you are only dealing with very basic structures like `Hoge` in this example, then you could just use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and skip the manual definitions.